# Adding sections and footer views in tableview - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How do i add a space between 2 sections in a tableView.

Once i added the following code in the

**titleForHeaderInSection**

```
if (section==0)
return @"sec 1";
else return @"sec 2";
```

then, the following

**viewForFooterInsection**

```
vi = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,100) ];
la = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,50)];
la.text=@"............long text..";

[vi addSubView:la];

return vi;
```

When i make the label Height to `30`, it displays 1/2 of the text. Therefore i will need to increase the Height of the label. Then when i increase the Height the 2nd sections Header overlaps. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the footer height in your tableview delegate, like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Switch here if you like different heights for footers
    return 50.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the `tableView`'s style. The style that you see is `UITableViewStylePlain`, where the sections are not separated. What you are looking for is `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. This can be given in two places.

If you are creating a `tableView`, use its initializer

```
UITableView *tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:someRect style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Or, if you are creating a `UITableViewController`

```
UITableViewController *tbvc=[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```